# How to upload a CSV file into R/shiny and automatically populate selectors based on column headers

Tags: r, csv, shiny

I want to upload a csv file from a \data folder inside the R project.

So far I've been reading questions, but most answers seemed a bit too fancy, with user interaction when selecting a data file.
I simply want R Shiny to read a data file (just the one) without any user interaction.

I have the standard files ui.R and server.R I place them in a working directory.

I have a csv file with data which I place in a subdirectory called 'data'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be missing something, but this should work right?

```
df = rio::import("./data/my_filename.csv")
```